# sap.m.Table - Vertical Scrolling with Fixed Header

Tags: sapui5

I have one table having lots of data. Now I want to scroll vertically with table header fixed. can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```js
 onInit: function() {
   var data = new JSONModel("Model/data.json");
   this.getView().setModel(data);
   var otable = this.getView().byId("PlaceIt");
   otable.bindItems("/employees", new ColumnListItem({
     cells: [
       new Text({
         text: "{name}"
       }),
       new Text({
         text: "{Physics}"
       }),
       new Text({
         text: "{Chemistry}"
       }),
       new Text({
         text: "{Maths}"
       }),
       new Text({
         text: "{English}"
       })
     ]
   }));
   otable.setModel(data);
   var oScrollContainer = new ScrollContainer({
     height: "100px",
     vertical: true,
     focusable: true,
     content: [oTableItems]
   });
 },
```

```xml
<Table id="PlaceIt">
  <columns>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Student Name" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Physics" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Chemistry" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="Maths" />
    </Column>
    <Column>
      <Text text="English" />
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <!-- ... -->
</Table>
```

I tried using `sap.m.ScrollContainer` control but I'm not getting anything.

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/bayoxolumo/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: UI5 now supports fixed header out-of-the-box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823778/5846045

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer to let other readers know that this Q&A is resolved.

Answer (score 18):

[As of v1.54](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/d85ac223ad77d36ffe40ff30afca307d20d07dda), the property `sticky` is publicly available.

> *sticky*
>   Defines the section of the sap.m.Table control that remains fixed at the top of the page during vertical scrolling as long as the table is in the viewport.

Once its value is set to `"ColumnHeaders"`, the headers will stay fixed while scrolling.

[image: sapui5 openui5 ui5 sap.m.Table sticky fixed column headers]

Be aware that this feature is supported only by modern browsers.

---

- **Demo:** https://jsbin.com/ticivew/edit?js,output
- [Property description](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table/methods/setSticky)
- [Other sticky options](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Sticky)<sup>v1.56</sup> - The syntax for assigning multiple values in XMLView looks as follows:

  ```xml
  <Table sticky="HeaderToolbar,InfoToolbar,ColumnHeaders">
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you don't want to use `sap.m.Table`, but here's an example nonetheless:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function(oEvent) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({
            data : [
                {
                    "col1": "at curabitur vestibulum",
                    "col2": "porttitor pharetra rutrum",
                    "col3": 93
                },
                {
                    "col1": "hendrerit dui fringilla",
                    "col2": "adipiscing suspendisse lorem",
                    "col3": 36
                },
                {
                    "col1": "placerat vel placerat",
                    "col2": "suspendisse quis sit",
                    "col3": 9
                },
                {
                    "col1": "sagittis at sed",
                    "col2": "malesuada aliquam sit",
                    "col3": 26
                },
                {
                    "col1": "donec donec sed",
                    "col2": "dui tempor nunc",
                    "col3": 38
                },
                {
                    "col1": "sed vitae fringilla",
                    "col2": "vestibulum pretium dolor",
                    "col3": 17
                },
                {
                    "col1": "scelerisque curabitur orci",
                    "col2": "sit sollicitudin amet",
                    "col3": 16
                },
                {
                    "col1": "libero lacus pulvinar",
                    "col2": "lorem velit elit",
                    "col3": 15
                },
                {
                    "col1": "convallis in at",
                    "col2": "fringilla sagittis magna",
                    "col3": 35
                },
                {
                    "col1": "dolor magna sed",
                    "col2": "at turpis tortor",
                    "col3": 3
                },
                {
                    "col1": "elit mi tortor",
                    "col2": "quis aenean turpis",
                    "col3": 32
                },
                {
                    "col1": "ipsum et magna",
                    "col2": "amet massa aliquam",
                    "col3": 59
                },
                {
                    "col1": "eget magna at",
                    "col2": "pharetra amet porta",
                    "col3": 69
                },
                {
                    "col1": "magna et scelerisque",
                    "col2": "aliquam vitae nullam",
                    "col3": 4
                },
                {
                    "col1": "velit etiam odio",
                    "col2": "lorem lacus magna",
                    "col3": 28
                },
                {
                    "col1": "at scelerisque lorem",
                    "col2": "facilisis odio dolor",
                    "col3": 4
                },
                {
                    "col1": "amet ipsum massa",
                    "col2": "sollicitudin sed tortor",
                    "col3": 54
                },
                {
                    "col1": "velit tincidunt massa",
                    "col2": "risus tortor massa",
                    "col3": 7
                },
                {
                    "col1": "id amet adipiscing",
                    "col2": "aliquam vitae adipiscing",
                    "col3": 94
                },
                {
                    "col1": "lorem massa lacus",
                    "col2": "malesuada ac sed",
                    "col3": 27
                }
            ]
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    }
});


sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```css
/* extra CSS classes here */
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
      xmlns:l="sap.ui.commons.layout"
      xmlns:t="sap.ui.table"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
        <t:Table rows="{/data}" visibleRowCount="5">
            <t:columns>
                <t:Column width="100px">
                    <t:label><Label text="col1" /></t:label>
                    <t:template><TextView text="{col1}" /></t:template>
                </t:Column>
                <t:Column width="100px">
                    <t:label><Label text="col2" /></t:label>
                    <t:template><TextView text="{col2}" /></t:template>
                </t:Column>
            </t:columns>
        </t:Table>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need two tables.
First table will have only columns and second will contain items to be displayed with empty column headers.

Second table will be the content of `ScrollContainer`.

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HdXFryDUDivUQXyLCgkD?p=preview)

Comment: this code I tried, In which adding one more page, that I don't want. I  have created one application in that I want to impliment

Comment: One more thing..I have created table header in XML

Comment: I found the table header fix with vertical scrolling...please check it...Thanks

Comment: All the calculations for DOM elements should be done in `onAfterRendering` as in `onInit` event DOM is not loaded. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/wifuqa/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

To get your own example working, you have to use a ScrollContainer wrapped around the table with `vertical="true"` and `height` set to some value. And you need the attribute `sticky="ColumnHeaders"` on the table itself.

Here is the code from your JS Bin example modified to work:

```js
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");

// Controller definition
sap.ui.controller("local.controller", {

  onInit: function() {
    var data = [{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "100",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "L"
    }, {
      name: "asd",
      amount: "800",
      currency: "INR",
      size: "XL"
    }, {
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    },{
      name: "asd",
      amount: "454",
      currency: "USD",
      size: "S"

    }];
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    var table = this.getView().byId("tableid");
    var mytemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
      cells: [
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{name}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{amount}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{currency}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
          text: "{size}"
        })
      ]
    });
          table.bindAggregation("items",{
          path: "/",
          template : mytemplate
          });
    
  }
});

// Instantiate the View, assign a model and display
var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
});
oView.placeAt('content');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="temp">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title></title>

  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript" src="https://sapui5.ap1.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
  </script>

  <!-- XML-based view definition -->
  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View controllerName="local.controller" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
      <App>
        <Page title="My View" id="page">
          <ScrollContainer
            height="200px"
            vertical="true"
          >
            <Table id="tableid" sticky="ColumnHeaders">
              <columns>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="column1" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="column2" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="column3" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                  <Text text="column4" />
                </Column>
              </columns>
            </Table>
          </ScrollContainer>
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>


</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```